# Why is Python .title() sticky? Applying title case to future strings?

Tags: python, django, formatting, title-case

This is a strange one:

I'm trying to format a string in python (obviously), and when I use `string.title()`, it seems like python keeps applying title case to the string, even after applying other formatting to the string.

Here's my code:

```
    def format_trade_name(self):
        tr_name = self.trade_name.title()
        tr_cap = [
            'oxy',
            'depo',
            'edex',
            'emla',
            'pred',
        ]
        tr_join = '|'.join(tr_cap)   
        tr_regex = r'\b(?!(' +tr_join + r'))(\w{1,4})\b'
        tr_matches = re.search(tr_regex, self.trade_name,re.IGNORECASE)
        for i in tr_matches.groups():
            if i is not None:
                tr_name = re.sub(r'\b'+i+r'\b',i.upper(),tr_name)
        return tr_name
```

**Here's the problem:**
I want the function to capitalize the first letter of each word, and then convert all 4 letter strings (not in tr_cap) to upper case.  So if the original string is `tylenol depo er`, I want the formatted string to be `Tylenol Depo ER`

When I change the 2nd line to `tr_name = self.trade_name.capitalize()`,
my function changes `tylenol depo er` into `Tylenol depo ER` (`depo` is not capitalized).

When I keep the 2nd line as as written, `tr_name = self.trade_name.title()`,
my function changes `tylenol depo er` to `Tylenol Depo Er` (`Er` isn't upper case, even though the formatting was applied after using .title().

Can anyone explain to me why the string is being converted to Title Case, even after I try to apply new formatting?

**UPDATE**
So I fixed it, but I have no idea why it works.  I feel like there's some important principle that I'm missing.

When I change `tr_matches = re.search(tr_regex, self.trade_name,re.IGNORECASE)` to `tr_matches = re.search(tr_regex, tr_name, re.IGNORECASE)` it works.

So, this works:

```
    def format_trade_name(self):
        tr_name = self.trade_name.title()
        tr_cap = [
            'oxy',
            'depo',
            'edex',
            'emla',
            'pred',
        ]
        tr_join = '|'.join(tr_cap)   
        tr_regex = r'\b(?!(' +tr_join + r'))(\w{1,4})\b'
        tr_matches = re.search(tr_regex, tr_name ,re.IGNORECASE)
        for i in tr_matches.groups():
            if i is not None:
                tr_name = re.sub(r'\b'+i+r'\b',i.upper(),tr_name)
        return tr_name
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: First I'm trying to use `.title()` to Capitalize Every Word in the string (so `tylenol depo er` becomes `Tylenol Depo Er`) and then using `regex.sub()` to turn all 4 letter words (except for those listed in `tr_cap` into UPPER CASE (so `Tylenol Depo Er` becomes `Tylenol Depo ER`).  The problem is that, even after changing `Er` to `ER`, it still returns `Er`

Comment: 'er' is  in tr_name variable capitalized string  'Er' therefore re.sub will not find it

Answer (score 1):

You're not using your title-cased string throughout the function:

```py
tr_matches = re.search(tr_regex, self.trade_name,re.IGNORECASE)
```

Those matches will be lower case, but your re.sub is searching on a string with mixed case.

Switch the code to:

```py
tr_matches = re.search(tr_regex, tr_name, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Edit: If you want to upper case multiple substrings, re.search won't do, as it only matches one.  findall should do the trick, something like:

```py
tr_matches = re.findall(tr_regex, self.trade_name,re.IGNORECASE)
print(tr_matches)
for _, i in tr_matches:
    if i is not None:
        tr_name = re.sub(r'\b'+i+r'\b',i.upper(),tr_name)
        print(tr_name)
```

Edit 2:
re.sub() is flexible enough that you can remove the whole matching step and loop.
It can match each of your 1-4 digit words and upper case them with a lambda function:

```py
  def format_trade_name(self):
        tr_name = self.trade_name.capitalize()
        tr_cap = [
            'oxy',
            'depo',
            'edex',
            'emla',
            'pred',
        ]
        tr_join = '|'.join(tr_cap)   
        tr_regex = r'\b(?!' +tr_join + r')(\w{1,4})\b'

        tr_name = re.sub(
            tr_regex,
            lambda match: match.group(0).upper(), 
            tr_name
        )
        return tr_name
```

Comment: thank you!  That makes sense, and fixed the issue